# Is there a difference to creating your scene in the Game Engine or the 3D creation software?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

Hey I have a simple question which I am having trouble finding any info about it online.

Situation: I am making an island explorer game.

In Blender i am creating my islands and all the static objects with the island (Trees, rocks, folliage, buildings, etc.) and exporting this island & static objects together in 1 FBX file. Then in Unity3d I have my scene already done I don't have to perform the scene creation there, i can focus on developing the interactable objects.

When I want to make a new island I just use the same project in Blender and re-use my previous works if I want to. Then export the new island to unity3d.

Is this correct? Am I supposed to "dress" my scene in Unity3d or in Blender? Does it make a difference (performance wise)

What I understand is that when I export multiple islands that are reusing the same tree for example, in Unity3D even though these trees are the same they are in different fbx's. But this only affects project size afaik?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you are making. Unity has a lot of tools, specifically environment creation tools that are much faster and more powerful to use in Unity rather than import from blender, especially for laying out a scene and prototyping.

Tools to check out:

- ProBuilder (Asset Store)
- PolyBrush (Asset Store Deprecated) :(
- Terrain (Package Manager)

It is good that you are learning blender as for making characters / detailed objects its still the way to go.

Performance is based on verts / textures and won't matter if you make something in Unity or import from Blender.

Comment: It does matter tho, making a terrain in blender would eliminate Unitys ability to cull terrain chunks, or reduce complexity further away from view camera. Exporting complex scenes from blender may also affect Unitys frustrum culling ability.

Comment: Terrain does that automatically, there is a distance in which grass and trees will no longer show, I believe its terrain.treeDistance or something like that

Comment: That's vegetation distance it's a different thing

Comment: treedistance culls plants/trees/grass and the camera's clipping planes will cull everything else

Comment: It won't be able to cull complex meshes that's what i tried to say, and that's why making a terrain in blender is not that efficient unless ofc it's height map is exported

Comment: Oh I misunderstood you , yeah we are already agreeing with eachother that terrain is generally better in unity 'Unity has a lot of tools, specifically environment creation tools that are much faster and more powerful to use in Unity rather than import from blender, especially for laying out a scene and prototyping'